# Failed to authenticate a SQL Server certificate based login in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, authentication, certificate

I created a login based on certificate successfully I mapped a user also to it when I try to connect to server using SSMS it fails, when I checked the error logs it reveals this error

> Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server
> Authentication

I'm not using a password to connect as it is certificate based
Here is how I created the certificate

```
USE MASTER 
CREATE CERTIFICATE certif41120221152
    WITH SUBJECT = 'mycertLogin certificate in master database',
    EXPIRY_DATE = '12/05/2025';
GO
```

Here is my login

```
CREATE LOGIN mycertLogin FROM CERTIFICATE [certif41120221152];
GO
```

So what's wrong with this?

How can I fix this so I can authenticate my login given that I'm not using a password in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure you can login to sql server by certificate, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658820/what-is-the-purpose-of-creating-a-login-from-a-certificate

Comment: The [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) states "Logins created from certificates or asymmetric keys are used only for code signing. They cannot be used to connect to SQL Server. "

Comment: @DanGuzman I don't think so they are used also to connect normal users I did that couple years ago with legacy sql server versions but now it doesn't simply work again

Comment: @user2050269, add the code to your question that works in legacy SQL versions.

Comment: i'm not even sure how you are logging in by just certificate. Can you show the screenshot in ssms? if you don't have to specify a password, won't anyone be able to just login? and if you use windows authentication, it means you probably were just lucky before and the certificate part of the login was a red herring.

Comment: How exactly do you think you got this working previously? What steps did you follow? Even now MS-TDS (Tabular Data Streams protocol) still only supports the use of certificates for server authentication, not client authentication.

Comment: Aside... generally speaking, certificate based logins work on the basis that the server only has the public key portion of the certificate (registered against the login account) and the user proves ownership by using their certificate's private key to encrypt a random challenge.